# jquery light slider and highcharts image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm new to javascript and jquery and I'm trying to have it so that when I click on a data point on the chart, my image in the jquery slider will slide to the center of the screen, corresponding with a data point.

However when I click it nothing happens. I'm using the public method of the jquery slider and the click from the api highcharts.

```
y: 222,
    events: {
        click: function () {
            $('#light-slider').click(function(){
                slider.goToSlide(3);    
            });
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: Could you recreate your example as live demo ?

Comment: take reference from http://jsfiddle.net/izothep/gf48mmfa/4/  has an answer  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393746/javascript-highchart-photo-slide/33397123#33397123

Comment: In your code you are adding new event to `#light-slider` while you should only call `slider.goToSlide(index)`.