# Error Bars in High Charts: What to do when the x axis is divided into categories?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, categories, errorbar

I have a column chart which is divided into categories. I'd like to put error bars on every bar, but I'm not sure how to do this (or where to look it up). Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>SIS</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Search Inefficiency'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Experiment 1', 'Experiment 2', 'Experiment 3', 'Experiment 4'],
        },

        yAxis: {
            reversedStacks: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Search inefficiency',
                align: 'middle'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },

        series: [ {
            name: '0 degrees',
            type: 'column',
            data: [0.43,0.36,0.53,0.52]
        }, {
            name: '45 degrees',
            type: 'column',
            data: [0.94,1.00,1.22,0.87]
        }, {
            name: '90 degrees',
            type: 'column',
            data: [1.01,1.13,1.45,1.08]
        }, {
            name: '135 degrees',
            type: 'column',
            data: [0.78,0.95,1.36,1.00]
        },{
            name: '180 degrees',
            type: 'column',
            data: ["",0.48,0.83,0.62]
        }]

        // I want to retain the category clustering and give each column an error bar.  Not sure how to do it with the following error bar example:
        // series: [{
        //     name: 'Rainfall',
        //     color: '#4572A7',
        //     type: 'column',
        //     data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        // }, { 
        //     name: 'Rainfall error',
        //     type: 'errorbar',
        //     data: [[48, 51], [68, 73], [92, 110], [128, 136], [140, 150], [171, 179], [135, 143], [142, 149], [204, 220], [189, 199], [95, 110], [52, 56]]
        // }]

    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, repost separately.  SO is supposed to be an archive of problems and solutions.  Adding unrelated requests really muddies the waters.

Answer (score 0):

**Question1**

you can use plotLine to create error bar

```
plotLines: [{ 
            label: {
                text: 'Error Bar',
                x: 1.25
            },
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            value: 1,
            dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
        }]
```

See [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/onhfLqdm/40/)

For next question , to get an image on mousever 
  [See this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393746/javascript-highchart-photo-slide/33397123#33397123)

Comment: I'm looking to put a small vertical error bar on each column, like these: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/error-bar

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `data: ["",0.48,0.83,0.62]` - you have string there. If you want to have an empty point, use `null`, not `""`.

Now to answer the question: simply put your error bar series after respective column series, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/3ywmg1c7/

```
    series: [{
        name: '0 degrees',
        type: 'column',
        data: [0.43, 0.36, 0.53, 0.52]
    }, {
        type: 'errorbar',
        data: [
            [0.4, 0.5],
            [0.3, 0.4],
            [0.5, 0.6],
            [0.5, 0.6]
        ]
    }, {
        name: '45 degrees',
        type: 'column',
        data: [0.94, 1.00, 1.22, 0.87]
    }, {
        type: 'errorbar',
        data: [
            [0.9, 1],
            [0.9, 1.1],
            [1.2, 1.3],
            [0.8, 0.9]
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: This is great!  Is there something that can be done to ensure that the error bars are centered on their column?

Comment: Update: turns out the bars are shifted to the right when you don't specify a width for the chart.  But when a width is specified, the error bars look centered (for most widths)